# Do open Chalice Dungeons close when the game is beaten?

Tags: bloodborne

If I beat the very definitely final boss and go to NG+, will I lose the progress in my current Chalice Dungeons?

(I already know I get to keep the Chalices themselves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you bring your Chalice dungeons with you to NG+'s. So you don't have to be afraid of losing them when you beat the game and go to a higher difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

After unexpectedly beating the very definitely final boss in one go, I tested this myself.

**Chalice dungeons are still open with all progress when you return to the Hunter's Dream**

Comment: Does that really need to be in bold?